# HTTP Servlet set data response and check it via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, servlets

I've a web-app base on HTTP servlet. 
This is JS request to my servlet:

```
        $.ajax({
              type:    "POST",
              url:     url,
              xhrFields: {
                  withCredentials: false
               },
              data:{
                  "action"      : action_type,
                  "fingerprint" : fingerprint,
                  "user_id"     : user_id,        

              },
              success: function(data) {

                alert('sdp inviato!');

             },
              // vvv---- This is the new bit
              error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +
                          "error thrown: " + errorThrown
                    );
              }
            });
```

This is my servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


String action= request.getParameter("action");

UtenteModel um= new UtenteModel();
SDPLineModel sdpmodel= new SDPLineModel();

     if (action.equals("CheckFingerprint")) {

        String fingerprint = (String) request.getParameter("fingerprint");

        String user_id = request.getParameter("user_id");

        SDPLines sdpline = sdpmodel.findFingerprintNew(fingerprint, user_id);

        if (sdpline == null) {

            String message = "Fingerprint non valida!";

            System.out.println("Fingerprint not found! ");

        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Fingerprint found! ");
        }
    }
```

My question is: can anyone show me some example for modify my servlet and js code, setting a specific response data (for the two case, fingerprint found or not found) and how to check its value via JS code in success:function(data)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if i understand very well your issues is that you want to show the response coming from your servlet to the client trough JS code !! you can try this :

```
if (sdpline == null) {
    String message = "Fingerprint non valida!";
    response.getOutputStream().print(message);
}else {
    String message = ""Fingerprint found! ""
    response.getOutputStream().print(message);
}
```

so now in your AJAX request you will get that message in case your request was successfully done .

```
},
 success: function(data) {
     alert('message coming from your servlet is '+data);
     //here data will contain one of the messages depending on the if statement 
},
```

Comment: @pier92 glad cause it helped !! please if my answer was helpful you can check it as the right answer in order to help other people get it .

Comment: now when i try to check an invalid value i see 500 error in browser network console and  getOutputStream() has already been called for this response .. how can i solve this? I'm tryind adding response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();  after 
response.getOutputStream().print(message); in the two cases.. am i right?

Comment: @pier92 in every case you will get the `response` , so that you can just made an `if statement` on the value to check it if `valid` or not and then do not print anything !!